# Terminate next line of code when COM port not responding

Tags: c#, winforms, modbus

This is my code. I want to terminate the process and execute next line of code

```
Thread tParent = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    Thread t = new Thread(master.ReadCoils(slaveId, 13, numRegisters));
                    t.Start();
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    if (t.IsAlive) t.Abort();
                }));

                coilsstatus = master.ReadCoils(slaveId, 13, numRegisters);
```

My application freezes on

```
coilsstatus = master.ReadCoils(slaveId, 13, numRegisters);
```

On this line of execution, I want to terminate the execution after 5 seconds and execute the next line of code.

Comment: Seems you are not starting the first thread: `tParent.Start()`. Does it hit a breakpoint inside your ThreadStart argument?

Comment: Thread t = new Thread(master.ReadCoils(slaveId, 13, numRegisters)); actully this line giving me error  cann't convert from bool[] to system.threading.start

Comment: You don't really need: `new ThreadStart(`

Comment: the problem is that want to treminate that  coilsstatus = master.ReadCoils(slaveId, 13, numRegisters); line of code after 5 sec thats it

Comment: The somewhat predictable outcome of this code is that t.Abort() does not abort the thread.  It can't, code execution is buried somewhere deep inside an unmanaged modbus driver.  If this is really necessary, and surely it is not, then you'll have to run this code in another helper process that you can Kill().

Comment: how to run another helper process and kill that process

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code is below.  Note that ReadCoils() can be aware of being in a thread that was prematurely terminated by catching ThreadAbortException.

```
// This creates the thread that calls ReadCoils() or, in my case,
// waits for 10 seconds.
Thread newThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
{
    // I replaced the following with "Thread.Sleep(10 * 1000);" to test
    master.ReadCoils(slaveId, 13, numRegisters);        
});
// Run the thread
newThread.Start();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
if (newThread.IsAlive)
{
    // Stop the thread if it is still running.        
    newThread.Abort();
}
```

Comment: so here where to put my this code  coilsstatus = master.ReadCoils(slaveId, 13, numRegisters);

Comment: See my edited answer - you should be able to take the above code as-is.

Comment: but how to get value   master.ReadCoils(slaveId, 13, numRegisters);   this  i want retrun value also

Comment: when my device is responding me it giving me null value how to handle it now

Comment: its working but i am getting this error: System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Safe handle has been closed

Comment: That sounds like something specific to your setup (the ReadCoils() method).  You should run this in the debugger and see where the exception was thrown.

Comment: its not throwing error all time its displaying me certain time and i can't debug the readcoils because i  am accessing this method from dll

Comment: If you have source for ReadCoils() you should be able to debug it using mixed mode debugging: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbaht4dh.aspx

Even if you don't have access to the source you should still be able to figure out where the exception is coming from using the debugger.

But note the comment by Hans above - you may not be able to kill the method/thread.